# Inuition behind symbolic partial derivative of heat capacity?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chemistry

I am studying thermodynamics. I am trapped at this step. I know it's a chemistry but no one really helped me there.

This is a symbolic expression where:
$E = f(T, V)$
(or Energy is a function of T and V)

Then the derivative was calculated as this:

$dE = (\frac{dE}{dT})_{V} ~dT + (\frac{dE}{dV})_{T}~dV $

I just don't know how he get this expression. I know in a partial derivative you need to keep one variable constant, but how they are summed up like this? and why he equates with dE and not dE/dt?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right when you say that you need to keep one variable constant. But, since $E$ depends on *two* variables, you need to consider the contribution of both variables to know completely how $E$ changes with those variables. The [way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) to consider the contribution of each variable is simply summing then, and that is why the expression has two terms.

Furthermore, the expression provides a formula to calculate $dE$, i.e., an infinitesimal variation of $E$. An infinitesimal variation of $E$ must be proportional to the infinitesimal variations of $T$ and $V$, i.e., $dE = A dT + B dV$. If all those variables change with, say, time $t$, you can divide the expression by $dt$ (tip: don't do this if there are mathematicians close to you!) to obtain
$$
\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial V} \frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \frac{dT}{dt},
$$
i.e., the rate of change of $E$ is proportional to the rate of change of $V$ and $T$.

Comment: I am wondering about $dE = AdT + BdV$ , what is A and B, and how will this lead to the equation I wrote. By the way, the equation you wrote at the end is the next equation in the derivation, so there is a logical step skipped for me. (please note that this level of math is at least 3 years beyond my studying so please don't kill me)

Comment: I was not trying to derive your equation, only trying to show the meaning of it. If you change $T$ by an amount $dT$ and keep $V$ constant, you will see a change $dE$, that, by the way, is equal to $(\partial E/\partial T) dT$. Then, $A = \partial E/\partial T$, i.e., the heat capacity at constant volume. You can do the same thing changing $V$ and keeping $T$ constant. The point is that, to obtain the total variation of $E$ you need to sum both contributions, which leads to the equation in your post.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now. the problem is that in my handout they use d instead of delta, but I know you are right. That you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure that $\partial$ is actually called _delta_, but it is indeed the right symbol. If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it :)